# Appium Ruby Console (ARC) complains HTTP request path is empty (ArgumentError)

Tags: objective-c, ruby-on-rails, ruby, appium

I'm a beginner to appium, or even the language node.js or ruby. So I completely follow the tutorial when installing appium. When I ran the command `arc`, got the error:

```
/Users/kenmux/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http/generic_request.rb:27:in `initialize': HTTP request path is empty (ArgumentError)
    from /Users/kenmux/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http/request.rb:14:in `initialize'
    from /Users/kenmux/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.44.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:71:in `new'
    from /Users/kenmux/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.44.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:71:in `new_request_for'
    from /Users/kenmux/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.44.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:35:in `request'
    from /Users/kenmux/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.44.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:64:in `request'
    from /Users/kenmux/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.44.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:40:in `call'
    from /Users/kenmux/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/appium_lib-5.0.0/lib/appium_lib/common/patch.rb:118:in `raw_execute'
    from /Users/kenmux/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.44.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:101:in `create_session'
    from /Users/kenmux/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.44.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:68:in `initialize'
    from /Users/kenmux/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.44.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:33:in `new'
    from /Users/kenmux/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.44.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:33:in `for'
    from /Users/kenmux/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.44.0/lib/selenium/webdriver.rb:67:in `for'
    from /Users/kenmux/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/appium_lib-5.0.0/lib/appium_lib/driver.rb:477:in `start_driver'
    from /Users/kenmux/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/appium_console-1.0.3/lib/start.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/kenmux/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /Users/kenmux/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /Users/kenmux/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/pry-0.9.12.6/lib/pry/pry_class.rb:96:in `block in load_requires'
    from /Users/kenmux/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/pry-0.9.12.6/lib/pry/pry_class.rb:95:in `each'
    from /Users/kenmux/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/pry-0.9.12.6/lib/pry/pry_class.rb:95:in `load_requires'
    from /Users/kenmux/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/pry-0.9.12.6/lib/pry/pry_class.rb:117:in `initial_session_setup'
    from /Users/kenmux/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/pry-0.9.12.6/lib/pry/pry_class.rb:142:in `start'
    from /Users/kenmux/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/pry-0.9.12.6/lib/pry/cli.rb:201:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/kenmux/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/pry-0.9.12.6/lib/pry/cli.rb:70:in `call'
    from /Users/kenmux/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/pry-0.9.12.6/lib/pry/cli.rb:70:in `block in parse_options'
    from /Users/kenmux/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/pry-0.9.12.6/lib/pry/cli.rb:70:in `each'
    from /Users/kenmux/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/pry-0.9.12.6/lib/pry/cli.rb:70:in `parse_options'
    from /Users/kenmux/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/appium_console-1.0.3/lib/appium_console.rb:49:in `<module:Console>'
    from /Users/kenmux/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/appium_console-1.0.3/lib/appium_console.rb:31:in `<module:Appium>'
    from /Users/kenmux/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/appium_console-1.0.3/lib/appium_console.rb:30:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/kenmux/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /Users/kenmux/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /Users/kenmux/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/appium_console-1.0.3/bin/arc:66:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/kenmux/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/bin/arc:23:in `load'
    from /Users/kenmux/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/bin/arc:23:in `<main>'
```

Then what should I do? Am I missing something? I just cannot get over it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this same issue when I was at work and had a proxy server in my .bash_profile

Open up a terminal and type:

```
cat ~/.bash_profile
```

That will show you what is in your profile.

my .bash_profile had the below.

```
export http_proxy="http://127.0.0.1:8888"
export https_proxy=$http_proxy
export ftp_proxy=$http_proxy
export rsync_proxy=$http_proxy
```

To comment them out just add # in front of each of the lines. Then restart your terminal session.

Side Note:

When you type `user$ arc` from the terminal you will want to make sure you have appium running and the appium.txt file in the same directory where your running arc.

Lots of good stuff here -> [Ruby_Console](https://github.com/appium/ruby_console)

I hope that helps you or someone else.